# Rails 3.2.16 has_many collection build failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Have a legacy application in Rails 3.2.16 which evaluating for an upgrade and have found an issue when running tests related to an ActiveRecord association between two models.  The problem is that the when attempting to construct the associated collection it fails.

I've tested the same scenario is a simple test app using the [Ruby on Rails Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/getting_started.html) which works (details below).  The one difference between my test app and the legacy app is that the legacy app models have a number of validations on them.

The models are as follows (extra details removed for ease of reading):

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bookings
    ...
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :schedule
   validate :ensure_sufficient_capacity
   ...

   # validation custom method
   def ensure_sufficient_capacity
       errors.add(:base, "Not enough capacity") unless capacity_available_for_booking?
   end
end
```

The **bookings_controller** for the **new** action has the following sequence:

```
class BookingController < ApplicationController

  def new
      #find the named schedule
      @schedule = Schedule.find_by_name("myschedule")

      #build the booking
      @booking = @schedule.bookings.build(:name => "mybooking",...)

      @booking.save #fails to save
  end

end
```

Some observations:

1. The **booking** model has a validation on it which does a check onto a referenced schedule (the other side of the relation.  **Can failure on the validation cause a break in the association build ?**
2. Creating a test app as per the Rails Guides Post-Comments getting started example works with a sample of the output below shows that the has_many build operation works.

local> p = Post.new(:title => "foo")

local> #

local> p.save

local> INSERT into "posts" ("title") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id" [["title", "foo"]]

local> c = p.comments.build(:commenter => "bar")

local> #

local> c.save

local> INSERT INTO "comments" .......

Comment: What is the error? Is there a typo in bookings class definition, because I don't see it inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base. Can you debug the output of `@booking.errors.messages if @booking.errors.any?` and paste it here?

Comment: Yes - small typo when I tried to simplify the code to put into question.   There are no errors from the trace #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fccdb562700 @base=#<Booking id: nil, schedule_id: nil, user_id: 26976, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, position: nil, date: "2017-12-31", company_id: nil, int_schedule_id: 3330, start_time: "2017-12-31 09:00:00">, @messages={}>

Comment: it won't show the error during the build but when saving. If the custom validation doesn't add the error it won't appear in @booking.errors. Can you post the custom validations? it's probably that

Comment: The validation on the booking object is: `validate :ensure_sufficient_capacity`. with implementation as ` def ensure_sufficient_capacity
    errors.add(:base, "Not enough capacity") unless capacity_available_for_booking?
  end`

Comment: This `schedule_id: nil`, when you print the error, would possibly mean that a @schedule has not been found by your criteria. Can you check this by debugging `@schedule`?

Comment: Checked the instance for @schedule and it exists following the find_by_name method.  The exception gets raised in the validation operation where the booking asks to check the associated schedule, which is nil.  I'm running Rails 3.2.16 and Ruby 2.2.7 - wondering if there's an environment issue ?

Comment: I would move `@booking = @schedule.bookings.build(:name => "mybooking",...)` in the `Schedule.rb` model `before_save` method. Just thought of posting asking you if you need help solving this or you already solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - solved the problem.  It seems that it wasn't verifiable based on the code base that I had or the sequence.

The findings were as follows

- The test code validated that with a **has_many** relationship the *collections*.build for the associated object works and on the save adds in the id for the related object.
- Adding validations to the object on the **has_many** which fail will stop the database transaction on save causing a rollback.  This wasn't the problem as the validations were working ok and not returning **false**
- Testing the code on the production server (Heroku) worked ok, but the Git copy I had was wrong and so on checkout of the Heroku code, via `heroke git:clone -a appname` I setup and tested this against my local database and the whole thing worked.

All in all - it was my fault in not seeing that I had a different version of the codebase.  I had assumed that the legacy app provided to me on GitHub was the production version.  Unfortunately, as a result of some time based quick fixes, the previous owners had cloned, migrated and deployed to Heroku without an update on Github or connecting the Heroku deployment to Github.  This resulted in a disconnect to the source of truth and there was no documentation to point me in the right direction, requiring a lot of reverse engineering.

Anyhow a good reinforcement of the lesson - ***when it doesn't all add up it's often the simplest of errors causing the problem!*** Or even it didn't pass the sniff test.

Thanks to all of the suggestion in the comments from [Ruby Racer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399861/ruby-racer), [Pacuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2852104/pacuna),[Fabrizio Bertoglio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7295772/fabrizio-bertoglio) and I hope that I can reciprocate in the future.  I know that I learned some more tricks, especially about checking on the errors.